# Return only databases name that have stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I searched a lot here and other forums, but didn't find what I need. I have 97 databases on my SQL Server but only about 30 have stored procedures. I need to select the name only of databases that have stored procedures. I guess I need to use both query.

```
SELECT name FROM sys.databases
SELECT name, type FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE (type = 'P')
```

I guess I need to do a join with them, but don't know exactly how.

Thanks a lot for your time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this will gives you no of SP in each of the databases.

It uses `Dynamic SQL` to form the query for each of the database and then use `exec()` to execute the query

```
declare @sql    nvarchar(max)

-- Create a temp table to store the result
create table #temp (db varchar(100), cnt int)

-- Generate the dynamic query for each of the database
select  @sql    = isnull(@sql, '')
                + 'insert into #temp '   -- added this line to insert result  into temp table
                + 'select db = ''' + name + ''', count(*) from ' + quotename(db.name) + '.dbo.sysobjects where type = ''P'';'
from    sys.databases db

-- Print out the dynamic query for your reference / verification
print   @sql
-- clear the temp table
delete  #temp   
-- execute the dynamic query
exec    (@sql)

-- retrieve the result from temp table
select  db
from    #temp
where   cnt > 0
```

you can insert the result into a temp table and then query from there

Comment: I appreciate your answer, I tested here and it worked just fine, but unfortunately it's not what I need. I have 97 databases, but only 30 databases have SPs. I wanna select the name only of these 30 DBs

Comment: you can insert the result into a temp table and then query from there

Comment: Actually I don't need to know how many SPs I have on each DB. I just wanna select (return) the name of databases that have SPs. Some DBs don't have SP, so I don't wanna select them.

Comment: have you tried the query at all ? You will see that the query counts number of stored procedure in a database. It does not `select all` or return all the stored procedure

Comment: do you know how to create a temp table ?

Comment: Actually not, Squirrel. Don't need to put here the answer. I will search how to do that. I thought it was something easy to do. I'm wondering if I let cleared what I need

Comment: modified the query to include temp table

Comment: That's almost it, Squirrel. Thanks a lot. But that is a small problem. I copy your answer to my SSMS and executed. The first time it returned only 3 DB (i am at home). The second time I executed it returned 6 DB. The result doubled. The third time same 3 DB, but 3 times. I understood that I need to execute only the end of your answer (select db from #temp. But the problem that in my work I will need to put this inside a SP (im working on a API REST generator), so your answer will be executed a lot of times.

Comment: each time you run you insert the result into the temp table, you should clear it before each execution or it will be accumulating. If you are doing it in a SP, it will be fine as the temp table will be automatically dropped once it is out of scope. But now you are running it in query window, it does not auto-dropped

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168886/discussion-between-luiz-felippe-serrano-and-squirrel).

Answer (score 3):

you can use sp_MSforeachdb to loop all dbs

```
DECLARE @command varchar(1000) 
SELECT @command = 'IF ''?'' NOT IN(''master'', ''model'', ''msdb'', ''tempdb'') BEGIN USE ? ; IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sysobjects WHERE xtype = ''P'' ) select DB_NAME() END'
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command
```

Comment: Hi, sandeep. Thanks for your answer. Now I'm at home and try to figure it out how to do this that I need in my work tomorrow. At home in my SSMS I have only 2 created DBs + 4 dbs of the system. It is:
master
tempdb
model
msdb
ESTDB003 (this is from my work and have SPs)
TESTDB (this i created today and don't have SPs)

Your answer returned 6 selects, one for each DB of my SSMS. Each select with the list of SPs (if the DB has SPs)

Comment: I don't know if i explained correctly what I need. I apologize. In my case at home, from these 6 DBs, I only wanna select the name of DBs that have SPs inside. Sorry if I didn't explain correctly.

Comment: That's almost what I need. I created another DB and created a SP on it. When I execute your query it should return the name of this two DBs, and they where returned, but in two different results. I need them in same result

Comment: I didn't vote because It is not what I need, but it is close. Sorry about that